# Windows Phone 8.1 packaging , publishing and Install in phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Can anyone help me in installing Windows Phone Company app after creating package,
As i am getting an error saying that "can't install companies app" in windows 8.1.
If anyone who had already published a windows phone 8.1 can please tell me the step by step process to make my app get installed

Comment: Have you tried using you favorite search engine on that issue?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question , you created your app package and you want to install on your development device. 
Here is step by step solution

[How to deploy app in device](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dn632395.aspx)